# how to open a windows form using html link in c#

Tags: c#, xslt

I have two forms Form1 and Form2.In form 1 i have web browser.And i have a xsl which is designed with href tag in it.I want to open a form 2 when clicking on the link.Can any one help me how to give link of form 2 on href in xsl or any idea to open a form using html link?

Comment: Just to be clear... You have a Excel-File, which has a link in it, which when clicked should open your Application with Form2 as the start? And what does the web browser form have to do with anything?

Comment: No i don't have excel file. I have designed a form which display a html content in it that is form1 and the html content has a link label in it and when i click the link label i need to open a form 2 . can you help me

Answer (score 2):

Add a "fake" hyperlink `<a href="#FORM2">Form2</a>` and intercept it:

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Url.Fragment == "#FORM2") {
        new Form2().Show();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```